# $post->user->name not working (ErrorException Trying to get property 'name' of non-object) || Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel

I was trying to show the name who have posted the post. It was working well. But after a few days, It is showing an error (ErrorException Trying to get property 'name' of non-object). I was searching for a solution for the last few days. And I have found **laravel 8** introduced jetstream for authentication purposes. But I have already started with the **laravel ui**.

I have checked the model of mine. But I could not find anything which could solve the problem. Here are my codes.

**view**

```
  <!-- Main Content -->
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-10 mx-auto">
        @foreach ($posts as $post)    
        <div class="post-preview">
        <a href="{{route('singlePost',$post-> id )}}">
            <h2 class="post-title">
             {{$post->title}}
            </h2>
            <h3 class="post-subtitle">
             {!!$post->content!!}
            </h3>
          </a>
          <p class="post-meta">Posted by
            <a href="#">{{$post->user->name}}</a>
            on {{date_format($post->created_at,'F d,Y')}}


            || <i class="fa fa-comment" aria-hidden="true"></i> {{$post->comments->count()}}
          </p>
          
        </div>
        <hr>
        @endforeach
        <!-- Pager -->
        <div class="clearfix">
          <a class="btn btn-primary float-right" href="#">Older Posts &rarr;</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <hr>
  @endsection
```

**Model**

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;


use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Post extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;


    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User');
    }

    public function comments(){

        return $this->hasMany('App\Models\PostComments');
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Post;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class PublicController extends Controller
{
    //This is the function which is showing posts
    public function index(){

        $posts = Post::all();
        
        return view("welcome",compact('posts'));
    }

    public function contact(){
        return view("contact");
    }

    public function about()
    {
        return view('about');
    }

    public function samplePost(Post $post){
               return view('samplePost', compact('post'));
    }

   
}
```

Comment: Try `<a href="#">{{optional($post->user)->name}}</a>` to check and if you get no name for any Post record it means that one of the records in posts is not having a valid user_id value

Comment: Show controller code

Comment: @developer
I have edited the code and added controller

Comment: @Donkarnash
Thanks. I have checked that. And also the tables. Yes, I have deleted one user in between this. Problem solved. :)

Comment: Suggestion: you must always have relation constraints - foreign key constraint on user_id column on posts table `onDelete('cascade')` to ensure data integrity so that such errors do not occur and there's no orphaned record in the posts table